# ScaleRoute({this.page})

Tags: flutter, dart

The parameter 'page' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (Documentation)  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

```
class ScaleRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;

  ScaleRoute({this.page})
      : super(
    pageBuilder: (
        BuildContext context,
        Animation<double> animation,
        Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
        ) =>
```

The parameter 'page' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. (Documentation)  Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Answer (score 1):

You've defined  `final Widget page;` which is not nullable/optional. Add required like

```dart
  ScaleRoute({required this.page})
```

More about [null-safety/understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety).